Any efficient ways to find the smallest number k such that the sum of the digits of k^3 is equal to 1000?
From a(n) is the smallest number m such that the sum of the digits of m^3 is equal to n^3. we can find the first 6 items are: {1, 2, 27, 1192, 341075, 3848163483}
I have found and verified that a(7)=2064403725539899.
My conjectures:
a(8)  is a 23-digit integer.
a(9)  is a 33-digit integer.
a(10) is a 45-digit integer.
a(n) has about  $\lceil\frac{n^3 + 5.625}{23.2}\rceil$ digits.

How did you verify $a(7)$ ?

I've found that the largest sum of cubes of 15-digit integers is 342. So  a(7) needs at least 16 digits.  As 343 is only a bit larger than 342,  a 46-digit cube seems enough,we can narrow the candidate numbers  between $10^{16},  and  \ [10^{46/3}]$,and it's a luck to get 2064403725539899 as the solution.

And as $343\equiv 1 \bmod 9 $, so $a(7) \equiv {1,4,7} \bmod 9 $,only 1/3 candidate numbers  need to be verified.

$a(8)<= 99995999799995999999999.$
$a(9)<= 999699989999999949999999999999999.$
$a(10)<=199999999929999999999949999999999999999999999.$

$a(11)<=5999999999999599999999999999799999999999999999999999999999.$$a(12)<=999499998999999999999999999999999999996999999999999999999999999999999999999999.$

a(8)<=78729943070487891288719

K^3 must have a digit sum >= 1000. The first x with digitsum(x) >= 1000 is 1 followed by 111 9s, and we can find the smallest k with k^3 >= 1 followed by 111 nines, some k >= 10^31. Actually a big bigger. We check this k.
If the digit sum of k^3 is not 1000, we find the first x > k^3 with a digit sum of 1000. That’s probably 28 followed by 110 nines, or 37 followed by 110 nines, and we go on like this. Since digitsums >= 1000 won’t be much larger than 1000, it should not take long to find a k where the digitsum of k^3 equals 1000.

I think that your arithmetic is a bit off: If $k^3 \ge 2 \times 10^{111} - 1$, then the minimum $k$ should be on the order of $10^{37}$, not $10^{31}$.

To be precise, $k \ge 12599210498948731647672106072782283506$.

$a(5)^3 = 341075^3 = 39677989979796875$ So you can't just go on finding next $x>k^3$ with digit sum $=n^3$ because its  too slow, and you won't find one in time
